# Mobile detection in a website

Tags: mobile, web

I want a scenario where in I have a website and when I connect my mobile device to my pc or laptop, the website must be able to detect the phone and not the phone browser. As in it should detect if my phone is an iphone or any other mobile device. How can I achieve this?
Basically if I have a downloadable application and a list of compatible devices and when a device is connected, a compatibility check needs to be done and the software has to be downloaded directly! Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you must build an APP and not a WebAPP or website.

the browser cant send relevant information such MacAddress or IMEI then you cannot do it with a simple website.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can detect navigation browser and it has some extra information about the kind of device (like Android, Motorola, etc). For example [this](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).